# CONCAT SQL Query in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code but I am getting an SQL Syntax error;

```
$insert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$area1."')";
$insert .= "INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$area2."')";
$insert .= "INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$area3."')";
$insert .= "INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$area4."')";
$insert .= "INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$area5."')";
```

What is the correct way to carry out this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When inserting multiple tuples, this is the notation used.

```
$insert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '".$area1."')";
$insert .= ", (NULL, '".$area2."')";
$insert .= ", (NULL, '".$area3."')";
$insert .= ", (NULL, '".$area4."')";
$insert .= ", (NULL, '".$area5."')";
$insert .= ";";
```

Providing multiple INSERT clauses suggests separate queries; which could be acceptable depending on MySQL library, but each would need to be `;` terminated.

That said, you really should be using parameterized queries. When `prepare`d, their speed is usually comparable to this (outside of some larger bulk inserts).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the column names only once and then values separated by commas. eg

INSERT INTO students (Name, Age) 
VALUES
('John',10),
('Bob',10),
('Jeremy',10);

So just replace 
"INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES " in all statements except the first one with a comma "," and also insert semi colon at the end.

Answer (score 0):

USE This SQL Syntax (use `;`):

```
$insert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '$area1');";
$insert .= "INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '$area2');";
$insert .= "INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '$area3');";
$insert .= "INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '$area4');";
```

Or

```
$insert = "INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (location_id, location_name) VALUES (NULL, '$area1')";
$insert .= ", (NULL, '$area2')";
$insert .= ", (NULL, '$area3')";
$insert .= ", (NULL, '$area4');";
```